# ngRoute How to pass data to controller in other view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

> I want to pass the Response return by the $http.post to another
>   controller. I tried so many ways and also searched on the internet,
>   but i not reach to the point.

Function "evaluateScore()" inside the factory called by controller 'evalCtrl'. i'm getting the proper output of function inside the factory.

```
.factory('EvalServ', function($http){
    var evalFactory = {};
    evalFactory.evaluateScore = function(EvalData) {
        $http.post('api/universities',EvalData).then(function(Response){
            return Response;
        });
    }
    return evalFactory;
})
```

Below is my controllers which calls the function "evaluateScore()" in above service
This controller is on Index.html page.

```
.controller('evalCtrl',function($scope,EvalServ){
    var app = this;


this.EvaluateForm = function(EvalData){

    EvalServ.evaluateScore(app.EvalData);

 }

});
```

I'm getting the proper output of function *evaluateScore()* in "evalctrl". **I want to pass that function responded data to "resultCtrl" controller so that i can show the result on the result.html page.**

Please tell me how to do that...
And below is my result.html page controller. *if anyone has any other idea to do that then write your answer.*

```
.controller('resultCtrl',function($scope,EvalServ){
 // i want that $http.post responce data here...   

});
```

Comment: instead of returning the `$http.post` directly, why don't you store the result of that return in your factory object?

Comment: i'm using ngRoute in my project @georgeawg

Comment: i'm new to angularJs so i don't have any detailed idea of factory objects. if you can explain me how to do that with a simple example then it will be helpfull for me..@Claise